# Where have the blogs gone?

Tags: bug, blog, blog-overflow

I have [just posted](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/wheres-the-elu-blog-gone) about the EL&U blog being gone and though I'd try the other blogs. They're all gone! (Apart from the main SE blog.)

[image: Legitimate blog post returning 404]

Where are the blogs?

Comment: works for me, looks like it was fixed

Comment: No repro, all blogs are accessible from [the main portal](http://stackexchange.com/blogs). Something on your end might poison the IP maybe, think I saw a report once.

Comment: Where did you get that link from?

Comment: Some seem to work, some don't. At first glance I notice that Islam, TeX and GIS don't seem to work here (all 404 pages).

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's working for sites that are at `blog.*.com` but failing for sites that are at `*.blogoverflow.com`. Somebody probably botched the redirect that goes from blogoverflow.com -> stackexchange.com/blogs.